# Regular expression for phone matching (+)NNNNN?

Tags: regex

Hi I need a regular expression for phone number looking like `+NNNNN`, where `+` is optional and `NNNN` are arabic numbers only (from 0 to 9).

The phone number must be between 3 and 20 symbols. I use the following expression `[+]{0,1}[0-9]{3,20}$` but it is not working correctly.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: What isn't working correctly? What errors do you get?

Comment: FYI, `[+]{0,1}` can be shortened to `\+?`

Comment: if I have +444+555 it is validated as correct. I need to validate the whole string, but when second part (+555) match expression it is stated as valid.

Comment: Try `^\+?[0-9]{3,20}$`

Comment: 10x, @LucasTrzesniewski. I will take that into account.

Comment: 10x, @jbaums. It is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't anchor the start of your pattern with `^` but you did it on the end with `$`

This should work:

```
^\+?[0-9]{3,20}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add anchor at the begining of the regex:

```
^[+]?[0-9]{3,20}$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[+]{0,1}[0-9]{3,20}$
```

should work, you have to use `^` to match from the beginning